# javascript open() method conflict

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie to js.
i am trying to grab the value of the `textbox` and display in new page.
but somehow when i click the button it shows the value for a second then redirects to the same form page.
Please tell me where am i doing it wrong? Thanks.
Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <strong>Enter your name in the box below, then click
        the button to see a personalized page!</strong>
        <br>
        <form id="newp" onsubmit="newpage();">
            Name: <input type="text" id="yourname" size="25">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit"   onclick="pressedbutton()" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    function pressedbutton()
{
    var thename = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
    document.open();
    document.write("<h1>Welcome!</h1>");
    document.write("Hello, " + thename + ", and welcome to my page!");
    document.close();

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please tell me where am i doing it wrong?

You are not preventing the default action of the submit event. When a form is submitted, the browser will load the URL defined in `action`, or reload the page if none is provided.

If you don't want the browser to do this, you have to prevent it. There are a couple of ways to do this.

You could `return false;` from the event handler:

```
onsubmit="return pressedbutton()"
```

and

```
function pressedbutton() {
    // ...
    return false;   
}
```

Or you could call the [`preventDefault` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) of the event object:

```
 onsubmit="pressedbutton(event)"
```

and

```
function pressedbutton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

---

Have a look at the [excellent articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to learn more about event handling. It also describes the differences between browsers.

Comment: How can use the data to be shown in a new page??like new html file?

Comment: There a multiple ways, it depends on what tools (e.g. server side language) you have at your disposal. Overall it really depends on what exactly you want to do with the data.

Comment: i mean at this page where i am coding, is it creating a new Page?

Comment: It does not magically create a new HTML file if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `document.open()` and then `document.write()` on an already loaded document, it will clear the current document and replace it with a new empty document.

If you just want to add some content to the current document, then you should use DOM manipulation.  Create new elements and add them to the current document.

For example, you could do this:

```
function pressedbutton() {
    var thename = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<h1>Welcome!</h1>Hello, " + thename + ", and welcome to my page!";
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    // prevent form submission
    return false;
}
```

---

In addition, your form is being submitted back to your server which is causing a page reload.  You can prevent that by either changing your button to a regular button, not a submit button or by preventing the default behavior of the submit button.

If you don't intend to submit your form, then just change the button from this:

```
<input type="submit"   onclick="pressedbutton()" value="Submit">
```

to this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="pressedbutton()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: tell me open() method creates a new temporary page??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini - see this [MDN reference on `document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues I see with your code.  The one that stuck out to me the most was:

```
document.open();
    document.write("<h1>Welcome!</h1>");
    document.write("Hello, " + thename + ", and welcome to my page!");
    document.close();
```

I personally think that anything involving `document.` is terrible because it overwrites much of the preset code you already had in place in the HTML file.

Instead, you can use:

```
location.replace(url)
```

This keeps everything in place, but instead TRULY loads a new page.
On the page that has url, you could either have the same document.write() script (which I do not recomment), OR you can have preset HTML on that page that would have what you're trying to accomplish, which I think is the better method.

Also, this was kind of bugging me:

Change

```
</form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </div>
```

to

```
        </form>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

It is good practice to keep your scripts at the end of the document, not inside elements.

Regarding storing the value, I would use the following code:

On the first page:

```
function pressedbutton(){
    var thename = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
    localStorage.setItem("Name", thename);
    location.replace("Page2.html");
}
```

In Page2.html (same folder), place similar code to what you had (in the javascript):

```
<script>
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "`<h1>`Welcome!`</h1>`Hello, " + 
localStorage.getItem("Name") + 
", and welcome to my page!";
document.body.appendChild(div);
</script>
```